# Getting deleted list name in sharepoint 2013 using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a requirement to get deleted lists from Sharepoint using CSOM.

I got to know about ChangeQuery . I am using following code to get deleted lists.

```
var web = context.Web;
context.Load(web);
ChangeQuery siteCQ = new ChangeQuery(true, true);
siteCQ.DeleteObject = true;
siteCQ.Update = false;
siteCQ.Add = false;
siteCQ.SystemUpdate = false;
siteCQ.Item = false;
siteCQ.Web = false;
siteCQ.RoleAssignmentAdd = false;
siteCQ.RoleAssignmentDelete = false;
siteCQ.GroupMembershipAdd = false;
siteCQ.View = false;
siteCQ.RoleDefinitionAdd = false;

var webChanges = web.GetChanges(siteCQ);
context.Load(webChanges);
context.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (ChangeList change in webChanges)
{   
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", change.ChangeType, change.TypedObject, change.ListId, change.Title);
}
```

I am getting list id from this. But I am always getting Title as empty. Please kindly help me to get List Name.

Or Please suggest me some other option to get deleted List Names

Answer (score 0):

Please set List object to search as "true". You are quering the changes for a specific object type. For example, if you wish to get changes for specific actions on specific object, use code snippet as below.

`//ChangeQuery siteCQ = new ChangeQuery(true, true);
   ChangeQuery siteCQ = new ChangeQuery(false, false);
   siteCQ.Item = true;
   siteCQ.Add = true;
   siteCQ.SystemUpdate = true;
   siteCQ.DeleteObject = true;`

In your case, inserting the below line after 4th should do the trick-

`siteCQ.List = true;`

Comment: Hi Satyajit, Thanks for your suggestion. In my case for this code ChangeQuery siteCQ = new ChangeQuery(true, true); default value for siteCQ.List  is "true" . So it wont work. Anyway I have added your code and checked . It didnt work. And also with list id which I got in the code I am not able to get list name as the list is already deleted